# Why aren't I able to set system property for my selenium webdriver (java)?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
public class Main {

    static Locators Locators = new Locators();
    static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\currentuser\\chromedriver.exe");
        ...
    }
```

i'm getting the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:11)
```

on this line :

```
static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

why am i getting this althought i have sys.setproperty defined and how can i fix it within my code?

Comment: You need to set the path before initializing the driver.  So move new Chromedriver() call below your system.set call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xiao Yu mentioned, you are trying to create the chrome driver instance before setting the path in system property. You can update the code as shown below

```
public class Main {
    static Locators Locators = new Locators();
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\currentuser\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver =  new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try folloing code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\currentuser\\chromedriver.exe");

        ...
        // init here
        Locators Locators = new Locators();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

in your code, the "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();" is executed just **before** the "System.setProperty....", and that is why you got this error.